# Creating a Formula to get the Desired Result from Data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying to create a formula that if `C2:M2` has 1 and more "MISSING" then result would be "MISSING".

If `C2:M2` all has "N/A" then result would be "N/A"

If `C2:M2` some has "N/A" and  some has "DONE" then result would be done.

I have been **unable** to add that if all has N/A then result would be N/A.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C2:M2,"MISSING")>0,"MISSING",IF(F2="","",IF(COUNTA(C2:M2)=0,"N/A",IF(COUNTA(C2:M2)=11,"DONE",IF(COUNTA(C2:M2)>=1,"MISSING")))))
```

IF there can be other well formula then please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=filter( 
  ifs( 
    countif(row(C2:M) & C2:M, row(C2:M) & "MISSING"), "MISSING", 
    countif(row(C2:M) & C2:M, row(C2:M) & "DONE"), "DONE", 
    true, "N/A" 
  ), 
  len(C2:C) 
)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xm2aGcWam7j9vFdSNfalbko4rt-RlUOb7bLuL9009bw/edit#gid=278956115). The formula is in cell `A2`.

Comment: Please show your *hand-entered* expected results in the sample spreadsheet, and explain *why* they would be the correct results.

Comment: I apologize it was mistake sorry to bother you.